# Optional CCK fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

1. Is there a module in Drupal to enable or not a text field or more in general a CCK field? For example a check box option: when this is checked a textfield appears below, otherwise it is not visible.
2. Is there a module to switch between 2 CCK fields? For example I have 2 text areas, and I can only fill one (the others should be automatically disabled). The user can decide which one to enable with a radio button or by checking a check box.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I haven't used it extensively, the [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module seems like it might do what you want.

Otherwise, you can check into using the Form API's [#ahah](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#ahah) parameter to roll your own.

Hope that helps!